# Acer Aspire 5250 won't boot from bootable USB

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, boot, acer-aspire, usb-boot

I took home my friend's Acer Aspire 5250 which currently has corrupted Windows 10. So, I thought of installing Windows XP (SP3) in it using a bootable USB. As of now, it doesn't pick the USB. I don't have any Windows CD so USB is the only option. It is running on InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev. 3.5 and I tried finding the Safe Boot and Boot Mode (UFEI, etc) options but they are not there. It doesn't load the already installed Windows 10 neither picks up the USB, I'm stuck.

Comment: you do realize that you can download a Windows 10 iso from MS when you have a license? Any particular reason why you want to install XP?

Comment: Because this laptop has 1 GB Memory and AMD Dual Core E300. Windows 10 may be too heavy for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the UEFI in BIOS menu by pressing F2, as soon as it boots up, on Boot tab choose Legacy instead of UEFI, after that choose boot priority order and make your USB device be first priority, still in BIOS menu go to main tab and enable F12 boot menu (if needed -just be be sure to select correct USB device) then reboot. Press F12 during boot and now you can see your USB device, you can proceed with installation of OS.

Comment: There is a boot priority order under Boot tab in which I can select the boot devices. I can't see any other option.

Comment: Which error is it showing when trying to load the corrupted OS, I am suspecting that some boot entries might be missing? In which case are you able to access the command prompt? Could you please post a screenshot of your BIOS menu?

Comment: It tries to repair the Windows with  a dotted circle animation. Then a Black screen.
How to post images here?